# Spatie Laravel Welcome Notification

Tags: laravel

did someone encounter this problem when trying to configure the welcome notification using Spatie

[image]

I don't have any WelcomeNotification Model. do i need to make one?

Comment: obviously you need to make one !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have created a notification in the model folder because you are using `$user->notify(new WelcomeNotification($validUntil))`. And, you are passing WelcomeNotification model into notify as a parameter instead of a notification class object, which causes error.

You need to create the notification in the `app/Notifications`. So, when you run this command it will automatically create the WelcomeNotification in the `app/Notifications` folder.

```
php artisan make:notification WelcomeNotification
```

Now, import `use App\Notifications\WelcomeNotification;` in the User model.